# Unresolved reference: accompanist

Tags: kotlin, apk, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I am simply trying to generate apk of my android jetpack compose project. But It is throwing error as Unresolved reference: accompanist. While building and debugging, I didn't face any error. Error is only when generating the signed bundle.

error: Unresolved reference: accompanist

I have added dependencies as

```
debugImplementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-insets:0.23.1"
debugImplementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.23.1"
```

using compose version as 1.1.1
and usage is:

```
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
SideEffect {
    systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(
        color = ColorPalette.surface
    )
}
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: why do you use `debugImplementation` and not `implementation`? Generating APK should use release version